# How to reference a child directory, that is part of cwd's path?

Tags: bash, shell, directory

Is there a generic way to reference a path that is nested an arbitrary level deep along the cwd?  This is *almost* like a reverse relative path lookup.

For example:

```
$ pwd
/Users/somebody/foo/bar/baz

$ echo /[3] <-- 3rd directory from / in current path
/Users/somebody/foo

$ echo ~/[1]   <-- 1 directory from ~ in current path
~/foo
```

Comment: Does this need to be done in bash? And how specific are you about the syntax? Could you call a function, say `func / 3` or `func ~ 1` to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

Put these functions into your `.bashrc`:

```
parent() {
        local count
        local arg

        count=$(($1+1))
        if [ "$2" = "" ]
        then
                arg="$PWD"
        else
                arg="$2"
                if [[ $arg != /* ]]
                then
                        printf 'Warning: "%s" does not begin with "/".\n' "$arg"
                fi
        fi
        cut -d/ -f1-"$count" <<< "$arg"
}

tparent() {                                     # The ‘t’ stands for “tilde”.
        local count
        local arg
        local home

        count=$(($1+1))
        if [ "$2" = "" ]
        then
                arg="$PWD"
        else
                arg="$2"
        fi
        if [ "$3" = "" ]
        then
                home="$HOME"
        else
                home="$3"
        fi
        if [[ $home != /* ]]
        then
                printf 'Warning: "%s" does not begin with "/".\n' "$home"
        fi
        if [[ $arg/ != $home/* ]]
        then
                printf 'Error: "%s" does not begin with "%s".\n' "$arg" "$home"
                return 1
        fi
        printf '%s' "~${arg/$home}" | cut -d/ -f1-"$count"
}
```

It uses `cut -d/ -f1-number`
to extract the first *`N`* components of a pathname. 
*`number`* has to be *`N`*+1
because the null string before the first `/` counts as the first field.

Usage:

```
$ pwd
/home/gman/stack/JW

$ parent 3
/home/gman/stack

$ tparent 1
~/stack
```

This can handle paths with spaces and tabs, but not newlines.